# How to allow only a particular word in the textbox using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My requirement is I have to allow the user to enter only '@' keyword. if the user enter the other keyword it should not display anything in the textbox.

```
<input type="text" />
document.getElementById('txtSearch').onkeypress = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 64 ) {
        alert('welcome');
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: is this a demo or a question?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DHCUg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restrict any word using the following code.

```
$("#IDofTextInput").on("keyup", function(){
    if(!("@".startsWith($("#IDofTextInput").val())))
  {
    $("#IDofTextInput").val($("#IDofTextInput").val().substring(0, $("#IDofTextInput").val().length-1));
  }
});
```